# node-qunit, code coverage tool

Tags: node.js

For nodejs backend server code Unit Testing, I am using node-qunit with grunt.
Is there any code coverage tool using node-qunit module?

Maximum code coverage tool I am seeing needs headless browser support, ex. PhantomJS, but if I run using this, then I get syntax errors for nodejs keywords, like "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require" etc.

So which tool I can use for code coverage for nodejs backend code testing using node-qunit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're solely testing backend code, there's no need to run the tests in a headless browser like PhantomJS. For running code coverage analysis in node, I can recommend [istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul).

But I'm not sure if it works out of the box with node-qunit. However `mocha` is a popular node.js test runner with a [qunit-interface](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#qunit-interface), and [qunit-mocha-ui](https://github.com/itaylor/qunit-mocha-ui) delivers QUnit's assertions for mocha. So you could migrate your tests with only little effort.